# Generating reverse words

Tags: java

i am a beginner in java and i am doing practiceit questions off the internet.I tried attempting the question but i dont understand the error.

Write a method called processName that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and that prompts the user to enter his or her full name, then prints the name in reverse order (i.e., last name, first name). You may assume that only a first and last name will be given. You should read the entire line of input at once with the Scanner and then break it apart as necessary. Here is a sample dialogue with the user:

Please enter your full name: Sammy Jankis
Your name in reverse order is Jankis, Sammy

```
public static void processName(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");

    String full=console.nextLine();

    String first=full.substring(0," ");
    String second=full.substring(" ");

    System.out.print("Your name in reverse order is: "+ second + "," + first);

}
```

Maybe i will go about explaining my code.So i try to break the two words apart.So i use substring to find the both words and then i hardcode to reverse them.I think the logic is right but i still get these errors.

```
Line 6
You are referring to an identifer (a name of a variable, class, method, etc.) that is not recognized. Perhaps you misspelled it, mis-capitalized it, or forgot to declare it?
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method substring(int,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    String first=full.substring(0," ");
                     ^
Line 7
You are referring to an identifer (a name of a variable, class, method, etc.) that is not recognized. Perhaps you misspelled it, mis-capitalized it, or forgot to declare it?
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method substring(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
    String second=full.substring(" ");
                      ^
2 errors
33 warnings
```

Comment: substring cannot take String argument as a second parameter. substring(int,int) is correct. What you have given is substring(int,String which is wrong.

Comment: You mean bth the paramaters have to be the same?Like if it is int,both parameters have to be int?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void processName(Scanner console) {
    System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");

    String[] name = console.nextLine().split("\\s");

    System.out.print("Your name in reverse order is: "+ name[1] + "," + name[0]);

}
```

Of course it only works if the name has 2 words. For longer names you should write a method which would reverse an array

Comment: Hi.I have not learnt split function yet.So is there other way to go about doing it?

Comment: I think no because you never know name's length. So you can't use substring as you tried. One way is to use indexOf() method to localize space position and then, knowing its position substring name correctly. However code would be much longer with this method. Also split method is very easy in use. Here is a nice example of usage: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method. It does not take a string as its second parameter.

```
  String first=full.substring(0," ");
  String second=full.substring(" ");
```

What you may want instead is the [indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method. First find the index of the space character. Then find the substring up to that point.

```
  int n = full.indexOf(" ");
  String first=full.substring(o, n); //gives the first name
```

Comment: Yes.it is indexOf.I kept mixing up with substring.Thank you so much(:

Answer (score 0):

As per Java API, `substring()` accepts either one int argument like `substring(int beginIndex)` and two int arguments like `substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)` but you are calling with String arguments. So you're getting those errors. More info can be found here
[String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

go to here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and read to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ex3_11_padString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
        String f_l_Name = console.nextLine();
        String sss[] = f_l_Name.split(" ", 2);
        System.out.print("Your name in reverse order is " + sss[1] + ", " + sss[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation